# "function call must have a constant value in a constant expression"

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have the following code:

```
constexpr unsigned long long power_function(const unsigned long long prime, const unsigned long long iterations) {
    return iterations > 0 ? prime * power_function(prime, iterations - 1) : prime;
}

/* Inside my Class Definition*/

private:
    static constexpr unsigned long long prime = power_function(-363, 1'000'000); //Error occurs here
```

IntelliSense complains that `power_function` is being used incorrectly. But for the life of me, I can't work out what the issue is. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, FYI.

Error messages:

```
Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant   Basic Server    c:\<snip>   28  
Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant   Basic Server    c:\<snip>   33
```

line 28 corresponds to the line where the return function is, and line 33 corresponds to the line where the constexpr is defined.

Comment: Does it compile?  Sometimes IntelliSense is wrong.

Comment: There's a [recursion limit in constexpr functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258525/can-constexpr-function-evaluation-do-tail-recursion-optimization), apparently. What does the Output window show? (Usually it has more context than what shows in the Error List.)

Comment: It does not compile. I've just added the error messages at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Cameron I think you're right. If I change it to 300 instead of 1 million, IntelliSense still complains, but the compile error goes away.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It resolves to a number that's slightly less than `1<<64`. It happens to be a prime number, hence my use of it.

Comment: @Xirema: that and the overflows(=wrapping) freak me out. Try to write code that documents these facts ;)

Comment: BTW, in c++14, you may do the loop and avoiding recursion for `constexpr` function.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not in Visual Studio, unfortunately. That functionality still isn't supported by VS2015.

Comment: You may use logarithm complexity to code `power_function` instead of linear to solve your problem.

Comment: Like [that](https://ideone.com/kZ7Api)

Comment: @Jarod42 Just letting you know that I ended up using your code for the final version of my code, but I had to fix a typo to do so: the recursive call to `power_function` needed to take `prime * prime`, not `prime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a recursion limit of 512 for `constexpr` in the gcc and clang compilers. Because the compiler interprets `constexpr` functions as inline functions (C++ Standard 7.1.5 subsec. 2), they must be resolved at compile time. If after 512 iterations the compiler cannot resolve the expression to a constant, it halts compilation and raises an error. The standard *recommends* a minimum of 512 for recursive `constexpr` function invocations, but does not *require* it (See Annex B [implimits] 2.38 in the standard).

This limit may be applied in Visual Studio, but I am unsure.

Comment: Not true. The standard would never set an upper bound. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258525/can-constexpr-function-evaluation-do-tail-recursion-optimization

Comment: You are right. The 512 limit is implemented in gcc and clang. I assumed it was required in the standard, but it never says that.

Comment: gcc and clang both allow this option to increase the recursion depth: `-fconstexpr-depth=<value>`, but it looks like Visual Studio does not support that option.